# How do I fill text-boxes in a gui application through command line?

Tags: python, windows, perl, console, ui-automation

I'm designing an **NLP** (Natural Language Processing) application in python and I want to use the following **UNL** (Universal Networking Language) EnConverter that is an executable gui - **3rd party** - application and only works on windows (I don't have its source-code) :

[image]

So, what I want to know is how can I program a console application that calls this EnConverter and press the "Setting" button then manage to fill the text-boxes in the following image:

[image]

When I click the "**Setting**" button, the previous window shows up... I want my application to fill these text-boxes, then press "**OK**"...
When pressing the "**OK**" button the application returns to the first window...
The last thing for the application (my application) to do is clicking the "**EnConvert**" button in the first window... See the the first image, please.

I know this is possible because my professor have done this job in **Perl**... And he refused to tell me how!!! I have researched the Internet but I got nothing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Win32::GuiTest](http://p3rl.org/Win32%3a%3aGuiTest). It can detect widgets, click buttons, write text to GUI etc.

Comment: That's for Perl... I want a library for Python. Thanks anyway mate.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [PyWinAuto](http://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/). It can detect widgets, click buttons, write text to GUI etc.

Comment: Thanks man, but I can't download it form there!! Any other useful links??

Comment: It's ok man I got it installed... Many thanks for your help :)

Comment: I have installed PyWinAuto and made a small program to fill the text-boxes... But when I filled the text-boxes, clicked "OK" then clicked "EnConvert" (on the first window) an error has occured saying that it cannot read the "dictionary file" which is the value of the first text-box (second window.)
I tried filling the text-boxes manually and the reason didn't show up... So the problem isn't from the dictionary file... Can you help, please??

Comment: You probably filled something wrong. Try absolute paths. Also add some delays to see what is really filled in and if it is correct.

Comment: BTW: Do you have version 0.4.0? Because as I recall it does not need SendKeys.

Comment: I will try that trick... And yes I have the 0.4.0 version... It just requested SendKeys when I installed it... Anyway, I will try that and get back to you...

Answer (score 1):

The [Windows Sendkey](http://www.rutherfurd.net/python/sendkeys/) package looks like it should be ideal this kind of thing.

From the page:

In this example, SendKeys is used to type "Hello World!" in notepad.

```
import SendKeys
SendKeys.SendKeys("""
    {LWIN}
    {PAUSE .25}
    r
    Notepad.exe{ENTER}
    {PAUSE 1}
    Hello{SPACE}World!
    {PAUSE 1}
    %{F4}
    n
""")
```

Comment: I figured out I couldn't install the PyWinAuto package unless I have SendKeys package already installed. Thanks man.